# 301 Url redirect using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am redirecting my old URLs to new URLs using htaccess, the URLs are not redirecting in as expected manner

**htaccess**

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


Redirect 301 /testing-url          /testing-link




## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

**Expected output**

www.example.com/testing-url   from  www.example.com/testing-link

but the redirected URL is redirected in the below manner

www.example.com/testing-url?/testing-link

how to override this, am using Godaddy server?

Comment: You are mixing `Redirect` and mod_rewrite. `Redirect` alone should be sufficient in your case.

Comment: @OlafDietsche I didn't get your point

Comment: The htaccess contains both `Redirect` and `RewriteRule`. `Redirect` should be all you need.